# Как правильно динамически добавить элемент в конкретное поле?

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/w9zdt2f4/2/#&togetherjs=428qJwcF6z

```
var calendar = document.getElementById('calendar-wrap');

calendar.onclick = function(event) {

    var target = event.target;
    while (target != this) {
        if (target.querySelectorAll('calendar-day')) {


            target.appendChild(div);
            return;
        }

        target = target.parentNode;
    }
};
```

Нужно по клику на день открывать блок с полями для ввода, вносить данные и по клику на кнопку добавить - переносить их в соответствующий день. 
Сейчас открывает блок с формами, но после клика на сгенерированном блоке пишет ошибку -

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element
>   contains the parent.

Прошу помощи, как правильно это реализовать.

Comment: `if (target.querySelectorAll('calendar-day')) {` данное условие всегда будет выполняться. И можно заменить его на `if(true)`